# Analog of Klein-Gordon equation from Proca action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetism, klein-gordon-equation

What would be the general form of Lagrange Equation when instead of a scalar field we have a vector potential?
has anyone derived the klein gordon equation for a corresponding vector potential Lagrangian?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, starting from a Lagrangian density of the form
$$
\mathcal L = -1/4 F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} + m^2 A_\mu A^\mu
$$
one can find the so-called Proca equation from the Euler-Lagrange,
$$
\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} + m^2 A^\nu = 0
$$
If the field is massless, one can choose the Lorenz gauge, $\partial_\mu A^\mu =0$. If the field is massive, $\partial_\mu A^\mu =0$ follows from applying $\partial_\nu$ from the left-hand side. In both cases, one finds that the Proca equation is equivalent to the Klein-Gordon equation,
$$
(\partial^2 + m^2 )A^\mu =0
$$
If the field is massless, we find Maxwell's equations in covariant form.

Comment: With a massive gauge field, there is no need for a gauge fixing choice. The equation $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu} + m^2 A^\nu = 0$ implies $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$ whenever $m^2 \neq 0$ (act on the first equation with $\partial_\nu$).

Comment: Ah yes thanks. I've tried to change it to add/correct that detail