# Deriving different spin Lagrangian from one equation

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-spin, field-theory

I'm looking at these three Lagrangian. They are the Lagrangians for spin 1 0 1/2 particles. I have been told that these equations were not 'derived' rather they were guessed and confirmed from experimental data. My question is, using hindsight, is it possible to derive all three of these equations from one equations. That is to say, we have one equation that gives us these three?

The Klein-Gordon equation spin 0
$$L=c^2\partial _\lambda \phi \partial^\lambda \phi ^* -\left(\frac{mc}{\hbar}\right)^2\phi \phi^*$$

Dirac Lagrangian spin 1/2
$$L=i\hbar c \tilde\psi \gamma ^\mu \partial _\mu \psi-mc^2\tilde\psi  \psi $$

The Proca equation spin 1
$$L=-\frac{1}{16 \pi}F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu} +\frac{1}{8 \pi} \left(\frac{mc}{\hbar}\right)^2A^\mu A_\mu$$

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/634362/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge.
The physical content of the equations you quote is quite different, namely the Proca and Klein-Gordon Lagrangian describe bosons, while the Dirac Lagrangian describes fermions, which obey different statistics. So if there existed a ''master equation', the fields it would describe would need to know about both statistics at once which doesn't sound right physically.

There are other notable connections though.
If you take the Dirac equation and you ''square it'', you get an equation which looks like the Klein-Gordon equation. This is due to the fact that both equations follow special relativity, particularly the relation $E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$.
Also, if you expanded the Proca equation you'd find it's similar to 4 Klein-Gordon equations. The intuition being that both Lagrangians describe bosons, but the additional spin-1 information in the Proca equation (which corresponds to boson polarisation) is hidden inside of four boson fields.

In short, the equations are interconnected, but describe different physics from each other, so a ''master equation'' is usually not talked about. Perhaps some BSM/SUSY/ST person might disagree however.

Comment: So if it is impossible to have a master equation, can we have one equation that gives both the Proca and Klein-Gordon Lagrangian since they are both describing bosons?

Comment: The Proca equation basically _is_ the ''master equation'' for the Klein-Gordon equation. This is most easily seen not from the Lagrangian, but from the equations of motion the two Lagrangians give. See [this link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88567/analog-of-klein-gordon-equation-from-proca-action) for example. Think of it this way: The field $A^\mu$ described by the Proca equaiton is actually a vector $A^\mu = (A^0, A^1, A^2, A^3)$, where each of there $A^n$s follow the Klein-Gordon equation separately.